# PHP permissions error - I need execute permissions?

Tags: php, linux, upload, chmod

I have written a PHP script for file uploading and for testing I gave my upload directory 777 permissions. The script works fine.

Now I want to remove execute permissions for obvious reasons, but once I do that, I get the following error:

move_uploaded_file([filepath]) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Just taking the permissions down from 777 to 776 causes this error to appear when I try to upload a file. I don't understand why having execute permissions should have anything to do with this - can someone PLEASE shed some light?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A directory must have execute permission to be accessible in Unix & Linux.

Quoting from [here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html):

> On a directory, the execute permission (also called the "search bit")
>   allows you to access files in the directory and enter it, with the cd
>   command, for example. However, note that although the execute bit lets
>   you enter the directory, you're not allowed to list its contents,
>   unless you also have the read permissions to that directory.

I agree with lserni that the fact that revoking execute permission on the directory for O (the third digit) causes the problem is worrisome as it indicates that the webserver is accessing the directory neither as owner nor as member of the group.  You should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

> Just taking the permissions down from 777 to 776 causes this error to appear

This shouldn't happen. You ought to be able to run with 770 permissions, i.e., the directory should be owned by the Website user ID, with the group of web server.

This way the owner and the webserver are both able to manipulate the directory and the data. Ideally the Web server serving your website ought to assume the same user ID as the website owner, and that way you can keep the directory mode 700 and have it read-writeable and listable only by you.

If the last digit of the permissions is biting you, it means that the server is running with permissions for "everyone", which may be okay for a development site but isn't too good on a shared site (imagine your passwords being readable by any other website owner in the machine).

However, if you're running on a test machine, the 777 permissions are okay. Directory executable bit does not mean executable (a directory can't be executed anyway) but merely 'listable'. Without that bit, you can create and delete files but you can't know whether they're really there, and `move_uploaded_files` is objecting to this situation.

There are other solutions (e.g. [chrooting each virtualhost in Apache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php#24152)); see also [What are best practices for permissions on Apache-writable directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635363/what-are-best-practices-for-permissions-on-apache-writable-directories)

Answer (score -1):

for removing the execute permissions you need to execute following commands..

```
chown -R nobody upload_directory
chmod -R 755 upload_directory
```

The first command changes the owner of your upload_directory and files under it to 'nobody' which is what php operates under. The second changes the upload_directory and files to only allow user access to writing. `-R` is for Recursive..